# How do I remove weekends and holidays from time series data

Tags: python, time-series

Thank you for looking at my question. I am trying to remove weekend and holiday days from time series data in fx market. I have used pd.bdate_range, but I am not sure how to implement it within the Primary book. Please lmk if you need anymore info.

Thanks for the help

```
Now = today.replace( second = 0, microsecond =0)
st = (today-timedelta(days = 14))
et=today
#Remove weekend
br= pd.bdate_range(st, et)
#Remove holidays

#Only time betweeen 7am to 5pm

PrimaryBook = _get_tsdb_primary_prices("audusd", st,et).fillna(method="ffill")
PrimaryBook = PrimaryBook.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
PrimaryBook = PrimaryBook.dropna()
PrimaryBookB = PrimaryBook.filter(regex=r'(BID|BSIZ)')
PrimaryBookA = PrimaryBook.filter(regex=r'(ASK|ASIZ)')
PrimaryBookB = PrimaryBook.filter(regex=r'(BID|BSIZ)')
PrimaryBookZ= PrimaryBook.filter(regex=r'(ASK|ASIZ)')
PrimaryBookZ
```

This is the outcome but I would like to remove the weekend day, holidays and have a time frame 7am to 5pm

```
    BEST_ASK1   BEST_ASIZ1  BEST_ASK2   BEST_ASIZ2  BEST_ASK3   BEST_ASIZ3  BEST_ASK4   BEST_ASIZ4  BEST_ASK5   BEST_ASIZ5
Time                                        
2021-07-22 08:41:36.625573856+00:00 0.73725 2000000.0   0.73730 6000000.0   0.73735 4000000.0   0.73740 5000000.0   0.73745 4000000.0
2021-07-22 08:41:36.630647614+00:00 0.73725 2000000.0   0.73730 6000000.0   0.73735 4000000.0   0.73740 5000000.0   0.73745 4000000.0
2021-07-22 08:41:36.635475238+00:00 0.73725 1000000.0   0.73730 6000000.0   0.73735 4000000.0   0.73740 5000000.0   0.73745 4000000.0
2021-07-22 08:41:36.640455282+00:00 0.73725 2000000.0   0.73730 6000000.0   0.73735 4000000.0   0.73740 5000000.0   0.73745 4000000.0
2021-07-22 08:41:36.660516225+00:00 0.73725 2000000.0   0.73730 6000000.0   0.73735 4000000.0   0.73740 5000000.0   0.73745 5000000.0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2021-08-05 08:41:29.025629378+00:00 0.73990 6000000.0   0.73995 4000000.0   0.74000 5000000.0   0.74005 5000000.0   0.74010 9000000.0
2021-08-05 08:41:29.450549198+00:00 0.73990 6000000.0   0.73995 4000000.0   0.74000 5000000.0   0.74005 5000000.0   0.74010 7000000.0
2021-08-05 08:41:30.346124376+00:00 0.73990 6000000.0   0.73995 4000000.0   0.74000 5000000.0   0.74005 5000000.0   0.74010 7000000.0
2021-08-05 08:41:31.586653810+00:00 0.73990 6000000.0   0.73995 4000000.0   0.74000 5000000.0   0.74005 5000000.0   0.74010 7000000.0
2021-08-05 08:41:31.840526198+00:00 0.73990 6000000.0   0.73995 4000000.0   0.74000 5000000.0   0.74005 5000000.0   0.74010 7000000.0
```

I really appreciate the help

Comment: please post a sample of your dataset so everyone can look at.

Comment: Is that ok for data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As holidays are country and year specific, you will need to use a package for this.

I would recommend to use `holidays`:

```
import holidays

for day in holidays.UnitedStates(years=2021).items():
  print(day)
```

will give you a list of datetime objects for all holidays in the respective year:

```
(datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), "New Year's Day")
(datetime.date(2021, 12, 31), "New Year's Day (Observed)")
(datetime.date(2021, 1, 18), 'Martin Luther King Jr. Day')
(datetime.date(2021, 2, 15), "Washington's Birthday")
...
```

Next step would be to cast your days to the same format:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{"id":1, "day":"2021-07-22 08:41:36.625573856+00:00"}, {"id":1, "day":"2021-12-31 08:41:36.625573856+00:00"}])

df.day = pd.to_datetime(df.day)
```

Afterwards it is easy to compare if the day is contained in the list of holidays:

```
df.loc[:,"isholiday"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.day.date() in [d[0] for d in holidays.UnitedStates(years=2021).items()], axis=1)

df
    id  day                                 isholiday
0   1   2021-07-22 08:41:36.625573856+00:00 False
1   1   2021-12-31 08:41:36.625573856+00:00 True
```

And same goes for the weekends of course as well by checking if the dt.[dayofweek](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek.html)  property is in [5,6] (zero-indexed days)

Answer (score 0):

I reset the index and then used dt.dayofweek <5 to remove weekends